# ng serve and ng build is not working

Tags: angular, systemjs, package.json

I downloaded this [github project](https://github.com/yfain/primeng_seed/) . this is working fine when I am using NPM START. but when I am using `ng serve` or `ng build` this is not working.  this is giving the error:

**error log**

```
Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be 
determined.The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.
Please make sure your package.json contains both
@angular/compiler-cli and typescript in devDependencies, then 
delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) 
and run npm install again.
```

I tried `npm install @angular/cli` inside the project. `ng serve` still not working. what I am missing or doing wrong. here is my package.json

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "angular-seed",
"description": "An Angular2+PrimeNG+SystemJS seed project",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "start": "live-server"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^2.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^3.0.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.0",
  "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
  "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.7.1",
  "primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
  "systemjs": "0.19.37",
  "zone.js": "0.6.21"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
  "live-server": "1.1.0",
  "typescript": "^2.0.0"
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your start script is `live-server` in your `package.json`.

If you want to work `ng serve` or `ng start` then need to generate `angular` project by `angular-cli`.This project isn't made by `ng-cli` that why you can't work.

Therefore, use `ng-cli` to make a project and it's easily to set up.Though it's not what you ask but I supported.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli

ng help
#test for your install completely

#if show the help logs
ng new PROJECT-NAME
cd PROJECT-NAME
ng serve
```

At last, it's impossible to use install `angular/cli` to start the `ng cli` , you even didn't got the `.angular-cli.json`.

Comment: Thanks @rach-chen , so is there any other way to add cli features in this existing project ?

Comment: @shivamSHARMA Only clone your component to your new project manually.

Comment: @shivamSHARMA first, new a cli project. and clone your `/src` to cli project  src . change the ngmodule routing to use.

Comment: @shivamSHARMA if you want to use `PrimeNG ` just import `PrimeNG ` and done.Don't waste time to solve this problem, costly.

Comment: ok thanks will try that. I just realized that my question should be how to add ng cli in an existing project. :)

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is because you are using systemJs and not Angular CLI app

take a look here on how to use angular CLI https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

@angular/cli is not the only needed when you need to run in ng serve theres a lot more. :D happy coding :-)

Comment: Thanks, but `ng help` is working in the app. so is there any way to use `ng serve` in this project.

Comment: it works maybe because you installed ng cli globally. so, ng help is working anywhere in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `@angular/compiler-cli` in your "devDependencies". Try

```
npm i --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli
```

(Unfortunately, your angular versions are pretty old. The versions across all angular packages in an app have to be compatible. It's best just to put this line, "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.0.0".)

You can remove @angular/cli from package.json. And, make sure you have globally installed angular cli. Try

```
ng --version
tsc --version
```

to make sure you have the necessary tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this project after trying to install bootstrap on an existing project. After much trying, and since this project was under version control Github, I did the following steps:

- Deleted the project folder.
- Created the project again
- Verified that the `ng build` was working again
- Run the `git stash command` to restore the original versioned files.
- Run npm install
- Run npm build

This way the project was saved "the hard way".